# Wx Python Messagebox RTL

Tags: python, wxpython

i am using this command, which should switch my layout to RTL but the message box is still LTR:
    self.SetLayoutDirection(wx.Layout_RightToLeft)

```
wx.MessageBox(text, title, wx.OK | wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
```

how do i transform it to RTL?
I searched google, but didn't find an answer